# Run a wordpress query every week

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

Good morning everyone. As the title say I'm trying to find a way to run a wordpress query every week to update a section in my site with the suggested posts of the week.

Looking around I've found the `wp_cron` feature, and it seems like the thing I'm looking for since I can't set up a cron job on the server. 
The problem is that I wasn't able to make it work.
I've created this try-function in my **functions.php**

```
add_action( 'cron_hook', 'cron_exec' );

if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'cron_hook' ) ) {
   wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'cron_hook' );
}

function cron_exec() {
  echo time();
}
```

And i call the action in my post page with the following code:

```
do_action('cron_hook');
```

This is my first attempt at wp_cron so maybe I missed something but I was expecting to get the same **time()** everytime I refresh the page since the function should be fired once a day, but I ended up having the current timestamp on every refresh.

I'd like to know if I'm using correctly the wp_cron function and if it's the right thing to use in this case or there are bettere methods to achieve this result.

Thank you for the help and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute cron every week you'll need something like this:

```
function custom_time_cron( $schedules ) {

    $schedules['every_week'] = array(
            'interval'  => 604800, //604800 seconds in 1 week
            'display'   => esc_html__( 'Every Week', 'textdomain' )
    );

    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'custom_time_cron' );

add_action( 'my_cron_hook', 'my_cron_function' );

if (!function_exists('mytheme_my_activation')) {
    function mytheme_my_activation() {
        if (!wp_next_scheduled('my_cron_hook')) {
            wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_week', 'my_cron_hook' );
        }
    }
}

add_action('wp', 'mytheme_my_activation');

if (!function_exists('my_cron_function')) {
    function my_cron_function() {
        echo time();
    }
}
```

The first function creates a new schedule - because you only have `houly`, `daily` and `twicedaily` as a [reccurance](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event).

Then you set up your scheduler. You check if there is a scheduled event with `!wp_next_scheduled`, and if it's not, you schedule the event

```
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_week', 'my_cron_hook' );
```

If you've already initialized a cron with a certain name, for it to get rescheduled you'll need to [wp_clear_scheduled_hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_clear_scheduled_hook).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand the logic behind the functions but if I try to call **my_cron_hook** in the page using `do_action('my_cron_hook')` I still get the current timestamp everytime I refresh. Is this the right way to call the cron or I misunderstand something? Thank you again!

Comment: The point of `wp_cron` is that it will run when ever someone visits your web site. So if in the 1 week no one visits nothing will be run. Since cron is 'global' in a sense, I wouldn't place it in a page. That's why you have a function `my_cron_function()` where you can say: I want to echo time, every week in this place on my site, using conditionals, hooks etc.

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to understand how cron should work, I'll try some functions to dig deeper in its functionality. If I find something useful I'll post here. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)