# How to use wordpress cron job with a custom function from the plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am devloping a custom plugin for woocommerce. In that plugin the functionality is like it will get all the users and send them email in every 24 hrs. So doing a work in every 24hrs even without visiting a site I think I need a cron job for that.
So by googling over wordpress cron job I got [wp_schedule_event](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) function. But here I
can't understand how to work with it? I mean how the function will work
here? I have my custom function to get all the users and send them email but how
to work that function with [wp_schedule_event](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) and how the [wp_schedule_event](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) function should be call
from the plugin so that if no one even visits the site it will work silently.
Any help and suggestion will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: [Tooting my own horn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888969/run-a-wordpress-query-every-week/35889244#35889244) :D

Server cron job (non wp) will execute irregardless if your site was visited or not, whereas wp_cron depends on site visit, but once someone visits it fires. But I think it's safer to use wp_cron, than server, because if the server crashes, and you missed the timestamp, the cron won't execute (from my limited understanding of cron jobs), whereas if for wp_cron it will run the next time someone visits, even if site was down...

Answer (score 2):

You need to map your plugin function to an action, and then schedule that action to the Wordpress cron.

```
// ---- Schedule cron event for custom plugin function.
add_action('init', 'custom_plugin_function_event');
function custom_plugin_function_event() {
    if (wp_next_scheduled('custom_plugin_action') == false) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'custom_plugin_action');
    }
    add_action('custom_plugin_action', 'custom_plugin_function');
}

// ---- Execute custom plugin function.
function custom_plugin_function() {
    // Do something here
}
```

The above example is for procedural code. replace `custom_plugin_function()` with your plugin function's name.

Comment: so this will work even no one visits the site? Because I can see you have used `init` hook and this hook needs to be run when the site is loaded. So to do that  someone  has to visit the site right? I want without visiting site the function should run

Comment: No, mate. It only executes when a user visits the site (the first time). That's how WP cron works. If you want to schedule a cron event even when no-one visits a site you have to do it the good old fashioned way via Linux cron.

Comment: I have used that but its not working. You can check that in my other question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316336/wordpress-schedule-event-not-firing-in-set-time?noredirect=1#comment60263930_36316336